# How to play a Sound Effect in Android

Tags: android, audio

I'm looking to do a very simple piece of code that plays a sound effect. So far I have this code:

```
SoundManager snd;
int combo;

private void soundSetup() {
    // Create an instance of the sound manger
    snd = new SoundManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Set volume rocker mode to media volume
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    // Load the samples from res/raw
    combo = snd.load(R.raw.combo);
}

private void playSound() {
    soundSetup();
    snd.play(combo);
}
```

However, for some reason when I use the `playSound()` method, nothing happens. The audio file is in the correct location.

Comment: For single sounds use `MediaPlayer` and for high-performance playback (e.g. in games with lots of sounds) use `SoundPool`. For efficient memory management, you should use a library to work with those classes: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-Audio

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you are using `SoundManager`? I would use `MediaPlayer` instead, here is a link to the Android Docs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

then it's as simple as

```
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.combo);
    mp.start();
```

---

Make a directory called "raw/" under the "res/" directory. Drag wav or mp3 files into the raw/ directory. Play them from anywhere as above.

Comment: Or simply `RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)` instead of `R.raw.combo`.

Comment: import android.media.MediaPlayer;

Answer (score 7):

i have also attempted using the top answer, yet it resulted in NullPointerExceptions from the MediaPlayer when i tried playing a sound many times in a row, so I extended the code a bit.

FXPlayer is my global MediaPlayer.

```
public void playSound(int _id)
{
    if(FXPlayer != null)
    {
        FXPlayer.stop();
        FXPlayer.release();
    }
    FXPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, _id);
    if(FXPlayer != null)
        FXPlayer.start();
}
```