# Game Sound effects in Android

Tags: android, audio

I am developing a simple game in Android. I want to add sound effects for each of the touch 
events. However I have add background sound effect that runs throughout the game. But
how can add tiny sound effect for touching any character of the game. For better understanding
following is my class design :
I have a main activity from where as view I'm calling my GameView class that extends 
surfaceView. For the bacground sound I just created the sound at mainActivity and then called
that GameView class as bellow:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer backgroundMusic;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         backgroundMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bg);


         backgroundMusic.setLooping(true);
         backgroundMusic.setVolume(10.0f, 3.0f);
         backgroundMusic.start();

        setContentView(new GameView(this));
    }
}
```

And following is my GameView class. I want to add sound effect here in this class onTouchEvent as bellow:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   //checking condition I want to give different sound here.

  }
}
```

I tried to do it as mainActivity (that is using MediaPlayer.creat() ), but it shows error.
Anybody knows how to add such sound effect on the basis of my class design ?

Comment: _"it shows error"_. And what is the error..?

Comment: The error shown is not runtime. Just my compiler says as below :
"The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (GameView, int)"

It may be because GameView is not an Activity class. However I do not why... @Michael

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For short sound effect like explosions, coin collections etc, it is better to use `SoundPool`.

You just need to create a sound pool :

```
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

In Lollipop and later:

```
AudioAttributes attrs = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .build();
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool.Builder()
        .setMaxStreams(10)
        .setAudioAttributes(attrs)
        .build();
```

This creates sound pool for max. of 10 sound streams (i.e. how many simultaneous sound effects can be played at any one time) and uses `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` as sounds stream.

Be sure to also set the volume control in your `Activity`, so the user is able to change the volume of the proper stream:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Than, you need to load sound effects into pool and give them their identifiers:

```
int soundIds[] = new int[10];
soundIds[0] = sp.load(context, R.raw.your_sound, 1);
//rest of sounds goes here
```

You need to pass a context to load method, so either you do this inside your activity, or get is from somwhere else.

And final step to play sound is to call `play` method:

```
sp.play(soundIds[0], 1, 1, 1, 0, 1.0);
```

parameters are:

- *soundID* a soundID returned by the load() function
- *leftVolume*  left volume value (range = 0.0 to 1.0)
- *rightVolume* right volume value (range = 0.0 to 1.0)
- *priority*    stream priority (0 = lowest priority)
- *loop*    loop mode (0 = no loop, -1 = loop forever)
- *rate*    playback rate (1.0 = normal playback, range 0.5 to 2.0)

You need to remember, that `SoundPool` should not use media files over 1MB, the smaller the files, the better effect and performance you have.

Be sure to release the `SoundPool` when you are done, or in `Activity.onDestroy`.

```
sp.release();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a great explanation! Well done. Could you / someone please edit / comment it as the SoundPool is depreciated?

Answer (score 2):

GameView is not a subclass of Context. Pass the Activity or the ApplicationContext to the Mediaplayer

Comment: I tried using MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.bg);
But it shows the same error. Any example code ????????

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following ...

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.combo);
mp.start();
```

I found it at [How to play a Sound Effect in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451092/how-to-play-a-sound-effect-in-android)