# play 3 audio files one after the other

Tags: android, audio

I have an array of audio files and I want to play 3 audio files one after the other, so as the gap in between them is not noticeable.
I am trying it using onCompletion listener but unable to do.

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if ((image100==1)&&(image10==0)&&(image1==1))
    {
        mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[0]);
        mediaplayer.start();
        mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[12]);
        mediaplayer.start();
        mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[3]);
        mediaplayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion : Merge your three sound file into one.

Comment: I can't. Actually I need them individually as well as together.

Comment: Yes keep them individually but make one new file which is mixture of all three file, It will save your time & code.

Comment: I have many individual files which require a lot of space and merging them together will require still more space. Any other option?

Comment: Oh, I thought this was the only case.

Comment: In API level 16 and later you can use `setNextMediaPlayer` to specify another `MediaPlayer` that will be automatically started as soon as possible after the current one has finished playing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the AudioTrack class to play your sounds. With it, you can get very close and even overlapping sounds. To use it, you create separate threads for each sound.

Here's the [AudioTrack reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) and here's an easy to follow [blog entry](http://www.martinhoeller.net/2012/01/13/developing-a-musical-instrument-app-for-android/) where the author implements a piano with arbitrary length and simultaneous sounds. In it, he loops very short duration sounds, but you could easily adapt that to longer, single-play sounds.

Answer (score 0):

If these 3 audio files are short sounds, like game sound effects or piano tones, you can use `SoundPool` for playing them.
Here is a link to the sample code:
[Game Sound effects in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272646/game-sound-effects-in-android)