# Sound effects Android

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I want to add sound effects for each of my player events like on death. Should I use soundpool or meidaplayer and how would I go about it? For better understanding following is my class design, I have a main activity class "game" from where as view I'm calling my "GamePanel" class that extends surfaceView and draws my whole game. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Game Class below.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Game extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    View v1 = (new GamePanel(this));
    setContentView(v1);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


}
```

}

and my GamePanel where I would like to have the sound played

```
   player.resetDY();
        if (!reset) {
            newGameCreated = false;
            startReset = System.nanoTime();
            reset = true;
            dissapear = true;
            explosion = new 
            Explosion(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explosion), player.getX(),
                    player.getY() - 30, 100, 100, 25);
             ///here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short sound effect like explosions, coin collections etc, it is better to use SoundPool.

You just need to create a sound pool :

```
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
```

In Lollipop and later:

```
AudioAttributes attrs = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .build();
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool.Builder()
        .setMaxStreams(10)
        .setAudioAttributes(attrs)
        .build();
```

This creates sound pool for max. of 10 sound streams (i.e. how many simultaneous sound effects can be played at any one time) and uses AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC as sounds stream.

Be sure to also set the volume control in your Activity, so the user is able to change the volume of the proper stream:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Than, you need to load sound effects into pool and give them their identifiers:

```
int soundIds[] = new int[10];
soundIds[0] = sp.load(context, R.raw.your_sound, 1);
//rest of sounds goes here
```

Check full answer here: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272646/game-sound-effects-in-android)

Comment: I built the soundpool under my onCreate Method in my game class, how do I link it to my Gamepanel to play the sounds?

Comment: to avoid editing my answer and many comment please kindly go through all this following links: [Sound source 2](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Android:Playing_Sound_Effects_With_SoundPool) 2. [GUI source1](https://dzone.com/articles/playing-sounds-android) 3.[Sound](http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game7.html)

Comment: go through above link the answer are there

Comment: for clear view watch  this video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkHlclRsY9A)

Comment: you re welcome don't forget to up vote this answer, thanks